# Rails: Unable to redirect_to the user id stored in the session hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

When a user logs in, I am storing the user id in the session hash like this:

```
session[:user_id]=user.id
```

Subsequently, when the user return to the home page of the site, I would like to redirect the user to his home page like this since he is already logged in:

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
    def show
        user = User.find_by(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
        redirect_to user if user
    end
end
```

The problem is that irrespective of the value of `session[:user_id]`, the user always gets redirected to `/users/1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method takes a set of conditions to evaluate - it can't be used with just a id.

The following code should work:

```
user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) method:

```
user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

Note that `find` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the record could not be found (`find_by` will return `nil`).

Comment: I should have used find instead of find_by.